# fix net::err_unknown_url_scheme whatsapp link on flutter webview #101145

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, whatsapp

am using the flutter webview plugin.
the problem is that there is a WhatsApp pop-up from the webpage and if I click on the WhatsApp icon from the webpage it displays this error message.
NB: I did not add this WhatsApp button on my app, but it automatically pops on the webpage

Below is the code I wrote, please tell me the options i have to solve this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class Digitalcoin extends StatefulWidget {
  const Digitalcoin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Digitalcoin> createState() => _DigitalcoinState();
}

class _DigitalcoinState extends State<Digitalcoin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
        url: "https://www.meechtv.com/#",

      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text ("Meechtv"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,

        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
    ),
      withJavascript: true,
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalUrl: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      withOverviewMode: true,

      initialChild: Center(child: Text("Loading...")),
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
    child: Text('MeechTv'),
    ),
    );

  }
}
```